# Like Statu Ajax Post Graph Api

Tags: php, jquery, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, status

I am using this code for likes status but since yesterday it does not work.
How can this be done a likes status using php & curl or ajax?

```
$statusid = $_POST['url'];
$ac_to = mysql_query("Select access_token From users order by rand() ".$limit."");

while($yaz=mysql_fetch_array($ac_to)) {
    $access_token = $yaz['access_token'];
    //Atııl Kurt
}
$params = array('access_token'=>$access_token);
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$statusid."/likes?access_token=".$access_token."";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the PHP or Javascript SDK to do a fql request via FB.api. You need to query the likes table seen here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/?refsrc=http%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Freference%2Ffql%2F&refid=9&_rdr

Javascript: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

PHP: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

View this question to see fql via cURL: [FQL Query from PHP using cURL returning "Method Not Implemented"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709520/fql-query-from-php-using-curl-returning-method-not-implemented)

Edit:

Javascript FQL example:

```
FB.api(
{
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid=me()'
},
function(response) {
    alert('Your name is ' + response[0].name);
}
);
```

You can view how to use the Javascript SDK by visiting my tutorial here: http://www.epixseo.com/index.php/facebook-php-3-3-1-and-javascript-sdk-graph-api-tutorial/

Comment: Yes is in my answer, i had to edit it to post thelinks, take a look

Comment: I looked at but Javascript page not understand something.
If you help with a code example?

Comment: view my edit for how to work with the javascript SDK, all you need to do in the FB.api fql.query example above is change the query parameter to select from the likes table

Comment: You cannot create likes through the API, you have to use the LIKE button from Facebook. In javascript, to see if someone presses like you can subscribe to the edge.create event